# Kendo UI ComboBox Loading delay

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I am working on web application (shipping domain) and using kendo UI for look and feel. While using kendo combo box I am facing an issue. In the database we have thousands of records in Vessel table which is bounded to a combobox, It took near about 6 sec to load if user wants to see all vessels (first time), but it took the same amount of time to get load second time also (that's the problem here) even it doesn't hit the Action method in controller (second time). I think its kendo's default functionality for combobox that if all records got loaded at 1st time (without filter) it will not send request to server to get the response for same request till we enter something in combobox filter, but if the combo box is getting load from the cache then it should't took the same time (6 sec) to load the combo box. I have searched for caching opting in kendo combobox documentation but no luck :( till now.
Here is my kendo combobox code:-

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(i => i.VesselId)
                                            .Name("VesselId").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                                            .DataTextField("VesselName")
                                            .Placeholder("Select Vessel...")
                                            .DataValueField("VesselId")
                        .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                                            .AutoBind(false)
                                            .MinLength(1)
                                            .Value(proFormaVesselId)
                                .Text(proFormaVesselName)
                                            .DataSource(source =>
                                            {
                                                source.Custom()
                                                .ServerFiltering(true)
                                                .Type("aspnetmvc-ajax")

                                                .Transport(transport =>
                                                {
                                                    transport.Read("GetFilteredVessels", "Common");

                                                })

                                              .Schema(schema =>
                                              {
                                                  schema.Data("Data").Total("Total");
                                              });
                                            })
                                            .Events(eve => eve.Change(@<text>
                                                function () {
                                                if (this.value() && this.selectedIndex == -1)
                                                {
                                                var dt = this.dataSource._data[0];

                                                this.text('');
                                                }
                                                }

                                            </text>




))
                                            )
```

here is action method:-

```
public JsonResult GetFilteredVessels([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var data = _IVesselService.GetVessel().Select(x => new
            {
                VesselId = x.VesselId,
                VesselName = x.Status == (byte)enumRecordStatus.Accepted ? x.VesselName : (x.Status == (byte)enumRecordStatus.Draft ? x.VesselName + "(D)" : x.VesselName + "(R)")
            }).OrderBy(x => x.VesselName);
            var result= Json(data.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            result.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return result;
        }
```

please don't get confused with this line of code `result.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;` previously i was getting error about the json lenth it too high issue, so I have settled it like this.
Now Combo box got loaded and took 6 sec but second time when I tried to load the same records (All records) it took 6 sec again even the breakpoin which I have placed on the `GetFilteredVessels` ActionMethod doesn't got hit. If combo box it getting load from cache then why it took 6 sec ?
I hope you understood my problem if not please comment I can explain more. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are loading thousands of records into the combo box then that is loading thousands of objects into the DOM which is what is probably taking the time. I would suggest you look at either enabling the `virtualization` feature of the combo box or present back a suitable number of items within the combo box e.g. 100 at a time. I faced a similar problem and my response times went from 6+ seconds to instant update.

Comment: Thanks for the response @DavidShorthose, yes I have seen the demo here http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/virtualization

Comment: but when i tried to use the .Virtual() method, its not available in this version I am using 2014.2.903.545 version of kendo, can you please tell me in which version of kendo I can find this method?

Comment: 2015 Q1 http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history/q1-2015 was when the virtualize feature was introduced. I would suggest you try it if you have an active license to update too. I would also suggest that you branch your code (assuming you are using some form of source code repo) as I think there were some breaking changes from 2014 to 2015

Comment: Thanks a lot man, god bless you :)

Answer (score 0):

as per @David Shorthose suggestion I found a temporary solution for this problem. Please refer to this [Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/virtualization) I am not selecting this as answer because may be someone or me can provide better solution for this, lets hope for the best. I am still looking doing research on it